# C# How to sort list of objects with string values

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting, icomparable

I need sort list of string values using `IComparable`:

```
10.1, 10.10, 10.11, 10.2, 10.3
```

Expected result:

```
10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.10, 10.11
```

Tried to use `list.Sort` but didn't work

Comment: any effort from your side? if you really want an answer means show the code that you are using

Comment: what if he doesn't have any idea, it is still a valid question

Comment: it is not broad, it's just sorting a list of strings using comparator

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting

Comment: @J.Steen relax take a deep breath, create your own site if you're too strict

Comment: Have you tried `listobject.sort()`

Comment: @neil yes I tried but it sorts bad for me : 10.1, 10.10....10.2, 10.3...

Comment: You will have to convert the values to double

Comment: @TonySixx - As you can see from the correct but over-reactive responses, for your next question, please also describe what you have tried to do and how you tried to solve it but failed to

Comment: I think I need split every string to array (10.1 to array 10 and 1) then use  pad to change 1 to 01 and then compare every part like 10 with 10, 01 with 10 and so on. I'm beginner with C# so i dont know how to make it work.

Comment: @TonySixx - I'd say good direction - that is kind of what I did below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is to sort by **the number after the decimal point** in the string. So, take only that part, convert it to a number and then sort. Using `Comparer` it will look like

```
List<string> values = new List<string> { "10.1", "10.10", "10.11", "10.2", "10.3" };

values.Sort((x, y) => int.Parse(x.Split('.')[1]).CompareTo(int.Parse(y.Split('.')[1])));
```

Or using linq it will look like:

```
var result = values.OrderBy(value => int.Parse(value.Split('.')[1]));
```

In the case you want to first sort by the second part and then by the first you can do:

```
var result = values.OrderBy(value => int.Parse(value.Split('.')[0]))
                   .ThenBy(value => int.Parse(value.Split('.')[1]))
                   .ToList();
```

*keep in mind that this solution is naive and assumes all your values have a `.` and that the 2 parts of it can be parsed into `int` - If it is not the case then you can use `TryParse`*

Comment: dont you mean double or decimal

Comment: @J.Steen and @Neil - I can't convert just to a double/decimal because then both `10.1` and `10.10` will be the same => `10.1`. That is why I split it into 2 segments and order by them desperately

Comment: @GiladGreen Point. I was looking at the expected result and wondering what was wrong with it - now I know. =)

Comment: @J.Steen - Ya :) that is why it isn't a simple double convert and sort that :) - but not too far from that. If you liked my solution please upvote, it is in your privileges ;P

Comment: @GiladGreen "Like" has nothing to do with it - I upvote correct answers. Which yours seems to be, so it gets an upvote. :p

Comment: @J.Steen - I do try to have only correct answers :)

Comment: This makes sense. Mistakes were made XD